# USB 3.0 to HDMI connector for GPU (displayLink)

Tags: hdmi, usb-3, adapter, displaylink

I have this monitor: Philips Brilliance 241B7QUPEB/00 
I takes video signals either using VGA or USB 3.0 It comes with a USB cable that is USB A to B.
I did not know that it was possible to stream video using USB 3.0, but apparently it is with displayLink. I can connect it with my laptop.

However, I also want to be able to connect it to my pc GPU. My GPU as either HDMI or DisplayPort. 
I cannot find an appropriate adapter that converts HDMI input signals to USB 3.0. Does it even exist?

Comment: Converters via [fiber optics](https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=38583) and [USB-C](https://www.monoprice.com/search/index?keyword=hdmi+to+usb3) do exist, as well as via USB-C _(wasn't sure if it's USB-C or not since the manual and product page didn't seem to specify)_

Comment: No, your monitor, supposedly this one https://www.philips.co.uk/c-p/241B7QUPEB_00/brilliance-usb-docking-lcd-monitor#see-all-benefits has an embedded USB3.0 HUB, not a video connection. The hub is independent of the actual monitor but supports audio input (as a generic USB audio device). It has nothing to do with the modern USB-C/Thunderbolt connections. Please read the full specs carefully to dispel your confusion.

Comment: @ChanganAuto The manual does state the USB 3.0 connection provides video

Comment: As I said, the monitor accepts USB video input and it works perfectly fine with my laptop. It is funny that many on the internet seem to argue this is not possible. Btw, see manual: This USB docking display combines the power of standard USB 3.0 hub, along with ethernet connection and stereo speakers. It allows you to connect your laptop to this display with a single USB cable delivering full HD video, digital audio and internet browsing.

Comment: I can probably also use something like this: https://nl.aliexpress.com/item/1005005676245796.html?spm=a2g0n.productlist.0.0.2ba53baarC9tIM&browser_id=05a5d23321304955b04d4cd30d2f1b5f&aff_trace_key=6e9e063385be47559eb34e67b0c893ef-1710277275329-00774-UneMJZVf&aff_platform=msite&m_page_id=lxqphvicqcavztmw18e3478f8f51121bc2b65ab7f5&gclid=&pdp_npi=4%40dis%21EUR%2124.34%2124.34%21%21%21186.50%21186.50%21%40210384b217102774926958854e1c7f%2112000035765707543%21sea%21NL%21780403615%21&algo_pvid=cab76a8e-07b1-45e3-8f7c-fdb88e4fd855 . With a. USB C to USB B adapter. But using VGA is much easier then.

Comment: If so it indeed relies on DisplayLink, a specific chipset present in many adapter cables and docking stations (and requires drivers that the OS may or may not include natively). That being the case there's no port adapter available. It is an USB device and that's all. It is, in a sense, an external (low-end) graphics "card" by itself. Again, no, the cable you just mentioned doesn't work. Your options are to use VGA (directly or via adapters) or the USB DisplayLink uplink, end of story.

Comment: @ChanganAuto thanks for your comment! Makes more sense to me now.